# How can I find out what quests I'm missing?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

On the Optional Quest Board, Stars marked with a red complete means you have completed every quest at that level, but stars with a blue complete means you have completed everything you have, but there are still quests at that level to be discovered/completed.

How can I find what quests I am missing? I have captured every monster in the game at least once at both Low and High Rank, so I don't believe it is the Special Arena quests, but I am still missing 7 star quest completions.

Is there a way to tell in-game what quests I am missing? Or do I have to resort to a resource like Kiranico and just sort of compare and go off memory?

Comment: Once you unlock it and clear it the first time they reappear randomly from that point on, but they'd always appear after capturing the first time.

Answer (score 1):

While it's hard to check if you've unlocked Special Arena quests, Optional Quests are unlocked in three ways, so you can make sure you've done each of those:

- Quest lines: these are quests given to you by various NPCs around Astera and the Research Base, marked with a "!". These quests must be completed in order, with new quests being unlocked only after completing previous ones. Some quest lines also include item deliveries, which will need to be completed in order to unlock more quests.
- Special Arenas: these quests involve fighting monsters in a specially-constructed arena, and are unlocked by capturing the monster to be fought. There are both Low Rank and High Rank versions of these quests, which require capturing a Low Rank and a High Rank monster to unlock, respectively. Not all monsters have Special Arena quests, and the quests themselves will randomly appear after clearing them the first time.
- Sight monsters in high rank: these are regular quests, but need to be unlocked by sighting the monster while on an expedition or a different quest. For example, sighting a High Rank Great Jagras while on an expedition will unlock a High Rank Optional Quest to hunt a Great Jagras. A certain monster, Dodogama, can only be encountered after gaining access to 8* quests, but its Optional Quest is found under 7* quests.

Comment: As an addition, capturing the High Rank version of a monster unlocks both the High Rank and Low Rank special arena quests.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to find out which I am missing, was to check [this list of quests](https://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunterWorld/comments/7xs4i0/complete_optional_quest_list_red/). From what I can tell, it has not been updated to include Deviljho (I believe he is 7* quest). Once you found out which quest you are missing, you can search for SOS-flares to join those quests (complete them and they should be unlocked for you)